# Existence and uniqueness of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

i'm dealing with this exercise that gives some linear transformations
defined using pre-image vectors and image vectors:

Does exist a linear application $T:R^2 \mapsto R^2$ such that

$T((1,0)) = (2,3)$ ; $T((2,0)) = (1,0)$ ; $T((0,1)) = (1,3)$

To find the answer i need to use this condition:

let $v$ be a generic vector,$T(v)$ it's image and $ax+by$ a linear combination equal to $v$

$$T(v) = aT(x)+bT(y)$$

Now what this equation is checking? The linearity?
later i found a theorem "Existence and uniqueness of linear transformation" that states

Give a linear transformation $F : V \mapsto V$ such that

$F(v_1) = w_1 ; F(v_2) = w_2 ... F(v_n) = w_n$

If the pre image vectors $(v)$ form a base , then exist and it's unique, otherwise

1. if the pre-image aren't a generator but are linear independent, the transformation exist and it's not unique
2. if the pre-image is linear dependent we need to manually check ( the expression that i mentioned before i assume )

so how all of this fits together? what's the intuition?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: if $T$ were linear, then in particar $T(2(1,  0)) = \ldots$?

Comment: T(2,0)? so (2,3) should be equal to 2(1,0) but it isn't and so it doesn't exist ok, the name linear transformation means that it is linear ok, but why with a base we don't need to check anything? Is it possible that that is a way to describe a general transformation but we are in **linear algebra** so we need a linear transformation and we check the linearity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> let v
> be a generic vector,T(v)
> it's image and ax+by
> a linear combination equal to v
> $$T(v)=aT(x)+bT(y)$$
> Now what this equation is checking? The linearity?

This is the meaning of linearity. A map $T : V \to V$ is said to be linear if and only if
$$ T(ax + by) = aT(x) + bT(y)$$
for all $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and for all $x,y \in V$.

---

Here's an explanation of the theorem you quoted:

---

A basis means by definition that for all $v \in V$ there exists unique $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ such that

$$ v = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i v_i$$
It follows that if $F$ is a *linear* map such that $F(v_i) = w_i$ then

$$ F(v) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i F(v_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i w_i,$$
and $F$ is uniquely defined.

---

If the $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly independent then $v_1,...,v_n$ forms a basis for a subspace of $ W \subset  V$. It follows by the first part that the restriction of $F$ to this subspace $W$ is uniquely defined. However the value of $F$ for vectors $ x \in V \setminus W$ is not defined so there are multiple possible linear maps to choose from.

---

If $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly dependent then we are the case of your example. We must check manually that their are no contradictions. In your example we have
$$ T(1,0) = (2,3) $$
$$ T(2,0) = (1,0)$$
$$ T(0,1) = T(1,3)$$
where $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ are linearly dependent. If $T$ is linear then we should have
$$ T(2,0) = 2T(1,0)$$
but this is not the case. Therefore $T$ cannot be linear so there does not exist a linear map $T$ such that

$$ T(1,0) = (2,3) $$
$$ T(2,0) = (1,0)$$
$$ T(0,1) = T(1,3).$$